# Refresh a VF page when SOAP API hits salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, streaming-api

A VF page is opened by a user and when a SOAP API hits the controller method I need show some values suppplied by the API to the VF page so that previous content of the page will be refrshed automatically without user refreshing the page manually. I know this can be done by STREAMING API but for that I need to have a DML statement, But in this scenario I dont want an   unwanted dummy DML statement. So I can get a functionality similar to straming Api?

Comment: How does your SOAP API "hit" the controller without a DML action? Are you you doing a callout and want the response to update the page?

Comment: Well there was a pilot of Generic Streaming may be you can have a look on it.

Comment: @JimRae  my controller is exposed as SOAP service and it just read data and supplies XML output to caller so I reaaly dont want DML statement.

Comment: @Avidev9 Can you please  provide the details?

Comment: Could you post the controller code?  My guess is that you have a Global method in a VF page controller, but that they would be isolated from one another from an interaction standpoint.  I don't think the page controller part of the class would be aware of the inbound webservice call, without some other type of interaction.